# Long double reseting to 0 after assignment

Tags: c++, c, precision, long-double

I've been tinkering around with some disease models in C/C++ and would like to get more precision out of it. I thought about using long doubles, for the 80-bit precision (I'm using cygwin`s GCC 4.8.3), but after making a calculation with it, I get a "nan" (not a number) output value. Here's the code I'm working with. All the variables are long doubles.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include <omp.h>
#include <cfloat>



using namespace std;

int
main ( int argc, char** argv )
{

    long double S, E, I, R, V, dS, dE, dI, dR, dV;
    long double a, b, g, t, c, d, e, f;
    long double dt = .005, tmax = 365;

    S = 318000000;
    I = 1;
    E = 0;
    R = 0;
    V = 0;

    FILE* F;

    F = fopen ( "valoresSIR1.txt", "w+" );
    //fprintf ( F, "Tempo, Susceptivel, Incubado, Infectado, Recuperado, Vacinado\n" );

    a = 0.000005; 
    b = 0.01;
    c = 0.05; 
    d = 0.000034; 
    e = 0.00000; 
    f = 0.0; 
    g = 0.000000;
    t = 0.0000;

    //printf("%Lg", a); exit(0);
    for ( long double i = 0; i < tmax; i += dt )
    {
        dS = ( - a * I * S - g + t * R + d * ( S + E + R + V ) - f * S ) * dt;
        dE = ( a * I * S - c * E - g ) * dt;
        dI = ( c * E - g - e * I - b * I ) * dt;
        dR = ( b * I - g - t * R ) * dt;
        dV = ( f * S - g ) * dt;


        S += dS;
        E += dE;
        I += dI;
        R += dR;
        V += dV;

        //printf ( "%Lg, %Lg, %Lg, %Lg, %Lg, %Lg\n", S, E, I, R, V );
        std::cout.precision (50);
        std::cout << S << std::endl;
        exit ( 0 );
        fprintf ( F, "%Lg, %Lg, %Lg, %Lg, %Lg, %Lg\n", i, S, E, I, R, V );
        switch ( ( int ) i )
        {
            case 0: std::cout << i << endl;
                break;
            case 100: std::cout << i << endl;
                break;
            case 200: std::cout << i << endl;
                break;
            case 300: std::cout << i << endl;
                break;
            case 4000: std::cout << i << endl;
                break;
            case 5000: std::cout << i << endl;
                break;
            case 6000: std::cout << i << endl;
                break;
            case 7000: std::cout << i << endl;
                break;

        }

    }

    fclose ( F );

    return 0;
}
```

Expected values for output: http://pastebin.com/mJqkSVUf

Comment: Which are the values of `tmax` and `dt` ?

Comment: I can ask lots of dumb questions like "Is S initialized?" or you could provide a compilable version of this code.

Comment: That code is far from complete and compilable. What do you expect anyone to do with that?

Comment: @void_ptr there you go.

Comment: @BillLynch there you go

Comment: Hm. http://ideone.com/6s8zXV So, just to be sure, the nan variable is `S` in your case, ie. the output?

Comment: There are uninitialized variables in your code, eg. `V`.

Comment: V is not initialized.   So it isn't a number and then neither is anything that depends on it.

Comment: What output did you expect and why?

Comment: @M.M the output should be decimal numbers which gradually "fill" the other fields (Such as E, I and R) and come to an equilibrium at some point. Instead, on the first iteration the loop outputs 'nan' for S, E, I and R.

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the answer -- instead, accept a posted answer. Otherwise it just makes it confusing for anyone else coming to the question.

Comment: @Pedro then edit your question and write all of these details there, not here in comments. And if the problem is the output value of S, E, I and R, please add code that prints them, so that we can see the problem when we run your program with no modifications. Right now you print them to a file after an `exit(0);`. Print them to STDOUT instead, and without the `exit(0);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calculation `dS = ( - a * I * S - g + t * R + d * ( S + E + R + V ) - f * S ) * dt;` uses the uninitialized variable `V`.  This causes undefined behaviour.

When undefined behaviour occurs, anything can happen. In your case it is being manifested as `nan` being the result of the operation involving `V`.